# Android camera not focusing. Crash when I try to setParameters

Tags: android, crash, camera, android-camera, autofocus

Ok, so I am using the metaio sdk, that launches the camera view. All works fine, but on the Galaxy S4 phone the camera is very blurry and also seems zoomed in. This is only happening on the Galaxy S4, on other devices the camera looks good.

When I try to set the camera parameters by adding this to my activity:

```
@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(int width, int height)
{
    super.onSurfaceChanged(width, height);
    Camera camera = metaioSDK.getCamera(this);

    Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
    Log.d("LEE","camera focused?"+parameters.getFocusMode());
    parameters.setFocusMode("continuous-picture");
    Log.d("LEE","camera focused?"+parameters.getFocusMode());
    camera.setParameters(parameters);

}
```

and I get a crash with these errors:

```
11-23 20:09:04.693: E/metaio-java(30060): Error in JavaScript: 
11-23 20:09:04.693: E/metaio-java(30060): Error in JavaScript: 
11-23 20:09:04.693: E/metaio-java(30060): Error in JavaScript: 
11-23 20:09:04.693: E/metaio-java(30060): Error in JavaScript: 
11-23 20:09:04.693: E/metaio-java(30060): Error in JavaScript: 
11-23 20:09:04.693: E/metaio-java(30060): Error in JavaScript: 
11-23 20:09:04.693: A/libc(30060): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x37333866 (code=1), thread 30146 (WebViewCoreThre)
```

Also if I try to set the focus mode in onSurfaceCreated(), I get no crash, but the camera view is still blurry.

```
public void onSurfaceCreated()
    {
        super.onSurfaceCreated();
        Camera camera = metaioSDK.getCamera(this);

        Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
        //Log.d("LEE","camera focused?"+parameters.getFocusMode());
        parameters.setFocusMode("continuous-picture");
        //Log.d("LEE","camera focused?"+parameters.getFocusMode());
        camera.setParameters(parameters);

    }
```

Any idea on why this is happening and how I can make it focus on the S4 also? How come acting different on different devices?

Comment: Do the 6 error messages from `metaio-java` only happen on S4? Or only when you call `parameters.setFocusMode()`? And where are your LOG messages? If they don't show, then the crash happens before you ever try to set the focus mode.

Answer (score 1):

Call Autofocus manually Whenever you want focus

Sample

```
 preview.camera.autoFocus(new AutoFocusCallback()
{
 @Override
  public void onAutoFocus(boolean arg0,Camera arg1)
  {
    preview.camera.takePicture(shutterCallback,
                                        rawCallback, jpegCallback);
 }
});
```